# Can't load .ONI device openni2

Tags: ros, c++, openni, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have previously saved a .ONI file that contains a recorded depth video. this was done so that the same video could be used for testing purposes. I am however having trouble loading this file to use. I keep ending up with "STATUS_NO_DEVICE" after the open line has been executed as shown here:

```
Status rc_ = openni::STATUS_OK;     
Device device_;
rc_ = OpenNI::initialize();  
char* fileaddress = "C:\\Users\\James\\DepthRecording1.oni";    
rc_ = device_.open(fileaddress);
```

As is stated in the OpenNI2 documentation this should be possible.
I have proven that the surrounding code is not an issue, by replacing the file address in the open function with ("openni::ANY_DEVICE") which successfully loads my 3D camera(Orbbec Astra S).

Any Idea of what needs to be added/ changed to be able to load the file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243530/can%27t-load-.oni-device-openni2/) by [Jiimmmbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27961/jiimmmbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-12**:
Suggestion: this question is rather specific to the OpenNI APIs/libs. I could be wrong, but I'd expect you to have a better chance at getting good answers at a forum more geared towards OpenNI development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can load oni file directly in this way: `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch device_id:=/path/to/your/file.oni`.
If it will not work, please refer here https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_launch/issues/26

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0